# BASH: How aggregate a file with export environment variable to property file

Tags: bash, while-loop, properties, export, let

I have this bash file:

**env_var.sh**

```
export BASE_PORT=8000
export WEB_HOST=https://microsoft.com
#export TEST_MACHINE=my.server.name
export DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
export APP_ROOT=$HOME/myapp100
export DB_URL=
export JMS_STORE=$APP_ROOT/../jms
let JMS_PORT=$BASE_PORT+425
export JMS_PORT
let HTTPS_PORT=$BASE_PORT+401
export HTTPS_PORT
export USE_CRED=yes
```

What I need is to convert above file to property file (key=value), so the result would be:

**env_var.properties**

```
BASE_PORT=8000
WEB_HOST=https://microsoft.com
DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
APP_ROOT=/home/admin/myapp100
JMS_STORE=/home/admin/myapp100/../jms
JMS_PORT=8425
HTTPS_PORT=8401
USE_CRED=yes
```

Meaning I need to:

1. Ignore lines which starts from hash #
2. Lines export JMS_PORT(without equal sign '=')
3. Lines with empty value like DB_URL(not urgent)
4. Off course calculate relevant port with **let** command

Answer (score 1):

<s>this works for the given format</s>

```
$ awk '/^#/      {next} 
       /^export/ {n=split($2,a,"="); if(a[2]=="") next; kv[a[1]]=a[2]; print $2} 
       /^let/    {split($2,a,"[$+]"); if(a[2] in kv) print a[1] kv[a[2]]+a[3]}' file

BASE_PORT=8000
WEB_HOST=https://microsoft.com
DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
APP_ROOT=$HOME/myapp100
JMS_STORE=$APP_ROOT/../jms
JMS_PORT=8425
HTTPS_PORT=8401
USE_CRED=yes
```

Comment: Thanks karakfa, this works. How can I make sure that instead of ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE in value, I will get actual values. Instead of APP_ROOT=$HOME/myapp100 i will get APP_ROOT=/home/admin/myapp100
Instead of JMS_STORE=$APP_ROOT/../jms I will get JMS_STORE=/home/admin/myapp100/../jms

Comment: OK, I missed that.  This is simple variable substitution in a give file for the given format.  This doesn't know the variables defined outside of the file context.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a script that sources `env_var.sh` and then uses a simple `awk` to print each variable and its value

```
cat props.sh
```

```
source env_var.sh

while read v; do
   [[ -n ${!v} ]] && echo "${v}=${!v}"
done < <(awk -F '[=[:blank:]]+' '!/^#/ && NF > 2 { print $2 }' env_var.sh)
```

now when you run:

```
bash props.sh
```

```
BASE_PORT=8000
WEB_HOST=https://microsoft.com
DB_DRIVER=org.postgresql.Driver
APP_ROOT=/Users/vogash/myapp100
JMS_STORE=/Users/vogash/myapp100/../jms
JMS_PORT=8425
HTTPS_PORT=8401
USE_CRED=yes
```

Answer (score -1):

```
. ./env_var.sh
cat env_var.sh | sed '/^#/d' | sed '/=$/d' | grep "=" | cut -d " " -f2 | cut -d "=" -f1 | while read line ; do eval "echo $line=\$$line" ; done > env_var.properties
```

Comment: This is so complicated, don't you think so?

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written

Comment: Please add some context to the _code snippet_ for the benefit of the future readers.

Comment: @vogash, please provide complete explanation of code with letting us know what didn't work from provided solutions so that all are aware of it.